# How to implement the find() function in Unix using recursive function (with C)

Tags: c, unix, recursion, tree, find

[find [path]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO5KP.png)

The way what i want it is shown in the attached picture.
I use Mac Terminal.
All i want to do is show the path with find function.

I want to implement the UNIX-find() command in C language.
There's a code i wrote, but I don't understand any of it, and I think it's too messy, so I'll ask you guys for help.
Isn't there a simpler code and one that's easier to understand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024

void do_ls(char[], char[]);
void print_error(int, char[]);

int main( int ac, char *av[] )
{
    if( ac == 1 ) {
        print_error(1, NULL);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s\n", av[1]);
        do_ls(av[1], av[1]);
    }
}

void do_ls( char path[], char dirname[] ) { // recursive func

    DIR *dir_ptr;
    struct dirent *direntp;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE] = "";

    strcat(buffer, path);

    if((dir_ptr = opendir(dirname)) == NULL) {
        print_error(2, dirname);
    }
    else {
        chdir(dirname);
        while((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr)) != NULL) {
            if(opendir(direntp->d_name) != NULL) {
                if(strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(direntp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                    strcat(buffer, "/");
                    strcat(buffer, direntp->d_name);
                    printf("%s\n", buffer);
                    do_ls(buffer, direntp->d_name);
                    strcpy(buffer, dirname);
                    if(strcmp(buffer, ".") != 0) {
                        strcpy(buffer, "./");
                        strcat(buffer, dirname);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("%s/%s\n", buffer, direntp->d_name);
                if(strcmp(buffer, ".") != 0) {
                    chdir("..");
                    strcpy(buffer, ".");
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

void print_error(int error_num, char dirname[]) {
    switch(error_num) {
        case 1:
            printf("usage : find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]\n");
            printf("        find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
            break;
    }
}
```

This is my code.
At first, I wrote the code without a buffer, but it didn't work. I thought I could understand it and solve it on my own, but I couldn't write the perfect code because I didn't have enough understand about C.

Comment: "Perfect code" and recursion are most often mutually exclusive. _Why_ exactly do you need to use recursion?

Comment: _There's a code i wrote, but I don't understand any of it_ .... that sounds very odd..

Comment: I referred to other codes because I did not fully understand C language...

Comment: @Lundin I don't necessarily insist on recursing, but I did because I thought it would be a better way.

Comment: macOS and POSIX have functions to assist in traversing a directory tree. Check the `fts` man page. Use `fts_open` to start a traversal, `fts_read` to process items, and `fts_close` to close a traversal.

Comment: Nonetheless, the code you wrote is not terribly complex, and it will not get any simpler doing it right with `fts` or any other method. There are plenty of details to handle when dealing with file systems, and you have to write code for that. Keys to managing complexity include truly understanding the code (do not guess at things; really understand the documentation and the routines you use); structuring the code to keep it organized and understandable; and documenting your code with lots of explanatory comments.

Answer (score 2):

You have a function that has a 5 level of nested conditional blocks, which is too much, because it is harder to read. You should try to create smaller functions, with one -or maybe 2- level. Moreover on recursive functions, the less it uses variable, the less it will eat your stack. Small functions often 
lead to functions that individually have smaller memory footprint.

The C, unlike python, is not seen as a *try something and see if it works*. Your second opendir may cause issues. let's say it opens the directory `/home/users/toto/work`. You opened your directory, and just after you will call do_ls which .... will open `/home/users/toto/work` an other time. Having the same directory opened twice... well, I have no idea if it works, but it is not good. Do not use opendir to see if a file is a directory, use `stat ( man 2 )`

You never close your directories. You won't be able to use your find on a big tree. In C you have to release manually every ressources that is not a chunk of memory stack.

Using a recursive function in that case is not a problem, in my opinion it is easier to implement this kind of program recursively. But it would be better to open a directory, store all it's content, close the directory, and then read through the stored content. So you always keep as few directory as possible.

Create a function that is dedicated to concatenante path components ( and which will ), when beginning, smalls functionnalities like this are often kinda boring to debug and you may want to have a dedicated and easy to test function to do this job.